# Почему клауза NULL ON NULL не возвращает значение в JSON_OBJECT?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle19c, oracle18c

Пытаюсь получить JSON `null` значение при передаче SQL `NULL` следующим образом:

```sql
select 
  json_object(key 'a' value a, key 'b' value b null on null)   c1, 
  json_object(key 'a' value a, key 'b' value b absent on null) c2
from (
  select 1 a, null b
  from dual
) t;
```

но, к сожалению, запрос возвращает такой результат:

```
|C1        |C2        |
|----------|----------|
|{"a":1}   |{"a":1}   |
```

Согласно документаации [JSON_on_null_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370), ожидал получить это:

```
|C1                 |C2        |
|-------------------|----------|
|{"a":1,"b":null}   |{"a":1}   |
```

Чего тут не хватает?

PS Использую Oracle XE 18c.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle JSON_OBJECT NULL ON NULL clause not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60620047) от участника [@Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60620047

Answer (score 5):

Участник [@BedaHammerschmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7577661/beda-hammerschmidt) (сотрудник *Oracle*) подтвердил [в ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60626013), что имеет место пока ещё открытый баг (воспроизводится в [19.08 на LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/l0sg7y4llrxyo0a30n5l17bmv)):

> Bug 31013529 - TWO JSON_OBJECT WITH DIFFERENT ON NULL HANDLER RETURN WRONG RESULTS

Как воркароунд можно воспользоваться скалярным подзапросом (*skalar subquery*):

```
select 
    json_object(key 'a' value t.a, key 'b' value (
        select t.b from dual) null on null) c1,
    json_object(key 'a' value t.a, key 'b' value (
        select t.b from dual) absent on null) c2 
from (
    select 1 a, null b from dual
) t;
 
C1               C2              
---------------- ----------------
{"a":1,"b":null} {"a":1}
```

---